# How do I get VertexList to work directly on older graphs defined using rules?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In MMA 8, it seems that sometimes `VertexList` will work with rule-based graphs without needing `GraphUtilities` and at other times it won't. Once it starts working, it keeps working until I restart MMA. In addition, while it is working, `VertexList` is not colored Red to indicate shadowing.

I know that I can use `` GraphUtilities`VertexList `` as shown below, but that is a bit much to type and I really want to understand why it is sometimes unnecessary. I also have dozens of notebooks with `VertexList` and don't really want to need to change all of them.

Here is what happens:

```
In[1]:= VertexList[{a -> b}]
During evaluation of In[1]:= VertexList::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in VertexList[{a->b}]. >>
    Out[1]= VertexList[{a -> b}]

    In[2]:= GraphUtilities`VertexList[{a -> b}]
    Out[2]= GraphUtilities`VertexList[{a -> b}]

    In[3]:= Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
    In[4]:= VertexList[{a -> b}]
    Out[4]= {a, b}

    In[5]:= $ContextPath = Rest[$ContextPath]
    Out[5]= {"PacletManager`", "WebServices`", "System`", "Global`"}

    In[10]:= VertexList[{a -> b}]
    During evaluation of In[10]:= VertexList::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in VertexList[{a->b}]. >>
    Out[10]= VertexList[{a -> b}]

    In[7]:= GraphUtilities`VertexList[{a -> b}]
    Out[7]= {a, b}
```

Is there any consistent way to force MMA to get VertexList to work on older style graphs without needing to use the full name?

One more detail. When this works, I get exactly this behavior:

```
?VertexList

VertexList[g] gives the list of vertices for the graph g.
VertexList[g,patt] gives a list of vertices that match the pattern patt. >>
```

which makes it look like the symbol is coming from `` System` ``

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. This problem was costing my student and I minutes to hours each time it happened.

Comment: You're welcome :) If it answered your question, you can mark it with the check mark (tick mark) to "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in function `VertexList` (or `` System`VertexList ``) requires that you input a graph object (i.e., something with the head `Graph`), whereas `{a -> b}` has the head `List`. So if you have a list of rules denoting the edges, then just wrap it in `Graph` for it to work. For example:

```
VertexList[Graph[{a -> b}]]    
(* {a, b} *)
```

---

The weird behaviour you see only when you load the `` GraphUtilities` `` package is because the package adds a definition to `` System`VertexList ``. Note that there is no such function as `` GraphUtilities`VertexList `` as you seem to assume in the question.

If you browse `$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Packages/GraphUtilities/GraphUtilities.m` you'll find the following in the code (line numbers in comments):

```
(* 449 *) u = Unprotect[{AdjacencyMatrix, EdgeList, VertexList}];   
(* 464 *) VertexList[x_?InternalGraphQ, r___] := With[{res = Network`GraphPlot`VertexList[x, r]},
(* 465 *)     res/;ListQ[res]];    
(* 483 *) Protect @@ u;    
(* 487 *) InternalGraphQ := Network`GraphPlot`GraphQ;
```

Essentially, the modification made is to simply call `` Network`GraphPlot`VertexList `` if your input is a list.

So to get a consistent behaviour for `VertexList`, you simply need to add the definition above and you needn't load `` GraphUtilities` `` just to get this behaviour.

Comment: This works for graphs without edge labels, but I've got a lot of code that was working without this approach before I restarted Mathematica and most of my graphs have edge labels, as in:`{{a-> b, "on"}}`

Comment: Well, then post a code sample that's representative of your actual graph. This is not what you showed in the question. You could try doing something like `list /. {x_, y_, _} :> {x, y}`

Comment: Sorry. The graphs I'm using have labels and are often multigraphs. And I know that I can do a number of things to get a `VertexList` from these kinds of graphs, but my question is really about why `VertexList` seems to work directly with these graphs (and yet is not colored Red) and why it sometimes doesn't. Perhaps I'm doing something strange with loading GraphUtilities or with $ContextPath. At this point, I cannot get back to where this is working again, but I have seen it happen several times in the past.

Comment: @ToddJohnson I poked inside the GraphUtilities (GU) package and it looks like it adds a definition to VertexList that's the same as ``Network`GraphPlot`VertexList``. You can try this in a fresh kernel: ``Network`GraphPlot`VertexList@{2 -> 3}`` and you'll get `{2, 3}`. This is the function that's being used when you load GU and pass a list to it. You don't see a red shadowing warning because ``Network` `` is not on `$ContextPath`. I'll add this to my answer after poking with it a little more.

Comment: I suspect that something, somewhere is adding a global definition for VertexList that is then getting used for lists. I'm just not sure what it is, because every time I've had this problem I start to modify code, then suddenly find that the VertexList starts working with the older graphs again.

Answer (score 1):

In versions 10.3+ `VertexList` accepts a set of rules as input.

[Documentation >> VertexList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexList.html):

[image]

```
VertexList[{a -> b, c -> d}]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d}
> ```

```
VertexList[{a -> b, c <-> d, a -> c}]
```

> {a, b, c, d}